# Binding doesn't work as described in MSDN

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

In WPF Databinding when `INotifyPropertyChanged` is implemented correctly should force a rendering event ot the GUI. Somehow I found an example where it doesn't. I want to bind an `ObservableCollection<Point>` to the `Points` Property of a `Polyline`. Hence `Points` only accepts `PointCollection` I need an `IValueConverter`. When the Converter creates a new instance of a PointCollection every time the bining works fine. But when I create a private field (of type `PointCollection)` in the Converter which stores the data and apply changes to it (e.g. add or remove `Point`'s) then the `Polyline` doesn't render!

XAML:

```
<canvas>
 <Polyline Stroke="blue" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Points="{Binding points, Converter=DataPointConverter}"></Polyline>
</canvas>
```

Converter:

```
class DataPointConverter : IValueConverter
{
private PointCollection privatePoints;
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    IEnumerable<Point> _enumerable = value as IEnumerable<Point>;
    if (_enumerable == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Source collection must be of type IEnumerable<Point>");
    }
    if (privatePoints == null)
    {
        privatePoints = new PointCollection(_enumerable);
        INotifyCollectionChanged _notifyCollectionChanged = _enumerable as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (_notifyCollectionChanged != null)
        {
            _notifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged += this.Source_CollectionChanged;
        }
    }
    return privatePoints;
    //next line would work! but i don't want to copy the entire list every time
    //return new PointCollection(_enumerable);
 }
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
private void Source_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
            for (int i = 0; i < e.NewItems.Count; i++)
            {
                privatePoints.Insert(e.NewStartingIndex + i, (Point)e.NewItems[i]);
            }
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
            for (int i = 0; i < e.NewItems.Count; i++)
            {
                privatePoints.RemoveAt(e.OldStartingIndex);
                privatePoints.Insert(e.NewStartingIndex + i, (Point)e.NewItems[i]);
            }
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
            for (int i = 0; i < e.OldItems.Count; i++)
            {
                privatePoints.RemoveAt(e.OldStartingIndex);
            }
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
            for (int i = 0; i < e.NewItems.Count; i++)
            {
                privatePoints[e.NewStartingIndex + i] = (Point)e.NewItems[i];
            }
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
            privatePoints.Clear();
            break;
    }
}
```

In fact the points are correctly added to the `Polyline` (i can see them  when i force a rendering event like changing the `Stroke` of the `Polyline`). But in my oppinion the binding should trigger rendering. (I even checked the `FrameworkPropertyMetadata`)

Am I doing something wrong? Or is that a undocumented "feature" of the .NET Framework?

My sources: Basicly I implement what Tamir Khason wrote in his [blog](http://khason.net/blog/creating-fully-binded-graph-control-with-wpf/). (The solution he offers for [donwnload](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/files/folders/5096/download.aspx) doesn't work. He never returns the value from the dictionary but always a new created Collection)

Comment: Can you please show your definition of your `Points` property?

Comment: @GarryVass, please remove your close vote. This question is *not* a duplicate of the one you showed. If you look at the [`Polyline.Points` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.polyline.points(v=vs.110).aspx), you'll see that it is in fact a `DependencyProperty` and therefore it is clearly possible to data bind to it. Thanks.

Comment: @Sheridan, as requested, all reverted.

Comment: I can see that you're not changing private list every time Convert is called, maybe that's the problem? You Create it with given values only first time, when it's null.

Comment: @Sheridan the property is pretty straight forward `public ObservableCollection<Point> points { get; set; }` plus the fact that i add the following lines `punkte.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(_punkte_CollectionChanged);` `void _punkte_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged("punkte");
        }`

Comment: @Sheridan pls change punkte to points.. i messed that up :)

Comment: Unfortunately, comments cannot be edited by anyone except the comment author, and they can only edit their own comments for around five minutes after leaving them.

Comment: I know that. i ment pls replace that in your mind ;)

Comment: I have a small project for [download](http://horrz.co.nf/Binding_Rendering_Test.7z)!

Comment: @MartinHoratschek, I noticed on the [`Polyline.Points` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.polyline.points(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN that the `Points` property is actually of type [`PointCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pointcollection(v=vs.110).aspx)... maybe you could try using one of those?

Comment: @Sheridan when you look at my question I convert to a PointCollection (otherwise the binding doesn't work at all). the problem is it doesn't implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` or `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the class is sealed so i can not add one of these interfaces...

Comment: Yes, sorry it's still a bit early for me. You don't seem to be using the `PointItem` class from your linked article... that seems to be a crucial part.

Comment: First of all. The Code of the linked Article doesn't do what he promises (I tested it and he never returns a PointCollection from the Dictionary he uses. He always creates a new one.) And his PointItem is the same as my ViewModel (in my downloadable project). As i think that is a better name for that object.

Answer (score 0):

can you  try  this  please

```
<canvas>
 <Polyline Stroke="blue" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Points="{Binding     points,Mode=TwoWay,updatesourcetrigger=propertychanged, Converter=DataPointConverter}">   </Polyline>
</canvas>
```

Comment: That doen't work. And I dont get the idea why twowaybinding should help (considering I didn't even bother implementing the ConvertBack method).